# Get HTTP response Using Shoulda Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, shoulda

I'm migrating over to shoulda from rspec and I can't seem to get access to the http response. Can someone point out what I may be doing wrong?

```
  context "doing somethin" do
      setup do
        get :index
      end
      @response.body
      should respond_with :success
  end
```

When i run this i get an error saying that @response is a nill object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the response you should first wrap into a "should" like this:

```
context "doing somethin" do
  setup do
    get :index
  end

  should "i access..." do
   assert response.status, 200
  end
end
```

It's like you try to use the response outside a test, each should represents a test case, and a context is like a before(:each) in rspec.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the shoulda syntax is:

should_respond_with :success

instead of:

should respond_with :success

Comment: should_respond_with :success macro was deprecated in v2.11.x in favor of using should respond_with(:success)